# Display alert message that's inside an action file, in another file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I have this php action file:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config.php';
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'signup') {

    $stmt1 = "SELECT * FROM users where username='" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
    $ret1 = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt1);
    $rowcount1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret1);
    if (empty($rowcount1)) {


        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, cpf)VALUES( '" . $_POST['username'] . "', '" . $_POST['password'] . "', '" . $_POST['email'] . "', '" . $_POST['cpf'] . "')";
        //echo $query;exit;
        echo  mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    } else {
        header("Location:signup.php");
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("User is already registered.")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
```

This else statement becomes true because I can see it in the console, but, I'm trying to display this alert message in another file called "signup.php".

I want to display the alert message right inside this small div:

```
<div class="cont">

</div>
```

I tried to do it with "header("Location:signup.php");" as you can see but no idea on how to make it work.

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: Include the alert code in `signup.php`.

Comment: Sorry, what's the correct way to do that?

Comment: Edit the `signup.php` page and include the `<script language="javascript">alert("User is already registered.")</script>` in that file. You can't echo that JS code in your "action" PHP file (and execute it) after you *redirect* the user to another page.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271812/javascript-alert-and-php-header

Answer (score 0):

Header('Location:') will redirect the user's browser. Nothing else will be displayed on the web page because the browser is being redireced. You need to add the  tag to the page signup.php.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config.php';
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'signup') {

    $stmt1 = "SELECT * FROM users where username='" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
    $ret1 = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt1);
    $rowcount1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret1);
    if (empty($rowcount1)) {


        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, cpf)VALUES( '" . $_POST['username'] . "', '" . $_POST['password'] . "', '" . $_POST['email'] . "', '" . $_POST['cpf'] . "')";
        //echo $query;exit;
        echo  mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    } else {
    // THE BROWSER IS HAS BEEN REDIRECTED TO signup.php
        header("Location:signup.php");

    // THIS ISN'T DISPLAY IN THE BROWSER BECAUSE THE BROWSER IS BEING REDIRECTED
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("User is already registered.")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? A location header will redirect the browser. It is a browser redirect.  `The Location response header indicates the URL to redirect a page to. ` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location  If you want to display something after a browser redirect, it must be on the new web page.

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271812/javascript-alert-and-php-header). Please avoid answering questions that have already been answered and/or should be closed. Instead you may link to duplicate questions or explain why the question should be closed in a comment. When you will have sufficient reputation, you will be able to cast [close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) when a question should be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it had been answered elsewhere. I will search before answering. (I had answered 10 minutes prior to someone noticing it was answered elsewhere). I was providing clearer instructions than your comment. And I would have put it in a comment (I originally did -- however, I figured the op wouldn't have understood it by their responses).

Comment: Any reason why you didn't close it as an already answered question?

Comment: I had close-voted already as off-topic because it lacks information to be able to provide a good answer which is why I then used the comment section to mention the duplicate (can't cast multiple close votes on the same question). I admit the duplicate vote is probably more accurate in this case.